# Convert a standard python key value dictionary list to pyspark data frame

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark

Consider i have a list of python dictionary key value pairs , where key correspond to column name of a table, so for below list how to convert it into a pyspark dataframe with two cols arg1 arg2?

```
 [{"arg1": "", "arg2": ""},{"arg1": "", "arg2": ""},{"arg1": "", "arg2": ""}]
```

How can i use the following construct to do it?

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    ...
]).toDF
```

Where to place arg1 arg2 in the above code (...)

Comment: You should edit your question, instead of "..." please show us where the "arg1" and "arg2" should go.

Comment: @betterworld ok done how to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers work, but here's one more one-liner that works well with nested data. It's may not the most efficient, but if you're making a DataFrame from an in-memory dictionary, you're either working with small data sets like test data or using spark wrong, so efficiency should really not be a concern:

```py
d = {any json compatible dict}
spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([json.dumps(d)]))
```

Answer (score 31):

Old way:

```
sc.parallelize([{"arg1": "", "arg2": ""},{"arg1": "", "arg2": ""},{"arg1": "", "arg2": ""}]).toDF()
```

New way:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from collections import OrderedDict

def convert_to_row(d: dict) -> Row:
    return Row(**OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())))

sc.parallelize([{"arg1": "", "arg2": ""},{"arg1": "", "arg2": ""},{"arg1": "", "arg2": ""}]) \
    .map(convert_to_row) \ 
    .toDF()
```

Comment: thanks, can you please answer the related question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584185/how-to-reduce-multiple-json-tables-stored-in-a-column-of-an-rdd-to-a-single-rd

Comment: Isn't this scala?  def convert_to_row(d: dict) -> Row:

Comment: Great. I just have a question, why 'sorted'?

Comment: @rado That is a Python 3 function annotation.

Comment: @Andre85 I think because the order of keys in each dictionary may difference that why we need to be sorted.

Comment: have not they made dictionaries as ordered dictionaries by default in Python 3.6?

Comment: how can you write this in Python2?

Comment: what happens if a key is missing, do we get null values or an error.

Comment: @652bb3ca In my case, some keys may be missed, and it will raise an error like `20 fields are required while 21 values are provided. `. How to solve it?

Comment: Note that of `Python 3.7` it is not necessary anymore to use `OrderedDict` since insertion-order became a standard behaviour for the normal `dict`.

Answer (score 22):

For anyone looking for the solution to something different I found this worked for me: 
I have a single dictionary with key value pairs - I was looking to convert that to two PySpark dataframe columns:

So

```
{k1:v1, k2:v2 ...}
```

Becomes

```
 ---------------- 
| col1   |  col2 |
|----------------|
| k1     |  v1   |
| k2     |  v2   |
 ----------------

lol= list(map(list, mydict.items()))
df = spark.createDataFrame(lol, ["col1", "col2"])
```

Comment: Even simpler: 
```df = spark.createDataFrame(mydict.items(), ["col1", "col2"])
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to modify the accepted answer in order for it to work for me in Python 2.7 running Spark 2.0.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row

spark = (SparkSession
        .builder
        .getOrCreate()
    )

schema = StructType([
    StructField('arg1', StringType(), True),
    StructField('arg2', StringType(), True)
])

dta = [{"arg1": "", "arg2": ""}, {"arg1": "", "arg2": ""}]

dtaRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dta) \
    .map(lambda x: Row(**OrderedDict(sorted(x.items()))))

dtaDF = spark.createDataFrame(dtaRdd, schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is a struct and not a string dictionary, you can just do

```
newdf = df.select(['df.arg1','df.arg2'])
```