# How to "reduce" multiple json tables stored in a column of an RDD to a single RDD table as efficiently as possible

Tags: python, concurrency, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Does concurrent access to append rows using union  in a dataframe using following code will work correctly? Currently showing type error

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
    StructField("owreg", StringType(), True),StructField("we", StringType(), True)
        ,StructField("aa", StringType(), True)
        ,StructField("cc", StringType(), True)
        ,StructField("ss", StringType(), True)
        ,StructField("ss", StringType(), True)
        ,StructField("sss", StringType(), True)
])

f = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
def dump(l,jsid):
    if not l.startswith("<!E!>"):
         f=f.unionAll(sqlContext.read.json(l))
savedlabels.limit(10).foreach(lambda a: dump(a.labels,a.job_seq_id))
```

Assume that sqlContext.read.json(l) will read a json and output a RDD with the same schema

The pattern is that I want to "reduce" multiple json tables stored in a column of an RDD to an RDD table as efficiently as possible.

```
def dump(l,jsid):
    if not l.startswith("<!E!>"):
        f=f.unionAll(sc.parallelize(json.loads(l)).toDF())
```

The above code will also no work as sc.parallelize is being invoked by the worker threads. Hence how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you store `savedlabels` as distributed data structure in the first place?

Comment: @zero323 it was a result of a prior computation.